Error while start griddb server on WSL Windows 11
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. When I am trying to start GridDB server it starting the server on WSL Without Systemd using the following command.

gs_startnode -u admin/admin

It is showing me the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gs_startnode", line 87, in <module>
    pid = util.getpid(pidfile)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/griddb-5.3.0/bin/util.py", line 191, in getpid
    fp = open(path, 'rU')
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid mode: 'rU'

I have using python 3.12.3.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

see: https://griddb.net/en/blog/install-griddb-on-windows-via-wsl/  (It says to enable systemd)

systemd is not available on WSL

Systemd support is now available in WSL!  (Article from September 21st, 2022)

Thank luuk but it should also work with gsadm

see here it seems solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78485502/not-starting-griddb-server-cluster-node

Does this answer your question? Not starting griddb server cluster node

Partially yes.There can also be other solution rather making change in python file of GridDB. That is, to install python3.10
